# Presenter mode of a Xaringan presentation does not sync

Tags: r-markdown, mode, presentation, presenter, xaringan

When I use Xaringan's presenter mode, the window (in chrome) showing the presenter mode and the window showing the normal view (another tab in chrome) are out of sync. IE, moving slides in the presenter mode window does not move the normal slides for the audience.

What could this issue be? I haven't

Answer (score 12):

Unbelievable. Literally a few hours after trying things and I accidentally discover the answer immediately after posting a question.

You've got to press <kbd>c</kbd> to clone the presentation not copy a window or tab using the web browser ("duplicate tab" in chrome).